# How to fix 'VSTest.Console.exe' is not recognized as internal or external command

Tags: system, mstest

i am trying to run my MSTest from the command line, and I cannot for the life of me figure out why this isn't working.  Yes it works if I manually change the directory to the executable, but I don't want to do that every time.

In the image below, you can see I have set up the environment variable, and yes I have restarted my computer many times.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

You need to add it to your `PATH` variable.  In that same dialog edit the Path variable and add the folder to the path. For example, I have enterprise installed, so I used this path:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow`

After updating the path you will need to close and restart the `cmd` window.